# back key not work with webview in android

Tags: android, android-webview

I have an activity with a  `WebView` component. when `WebView` is loaded completely in adv emulator, all thing is correct and back key finish my activity.

But when I test this activity with youwave emulator when I press back key the activity isn't finished. 
also I override  `onBackPressed()` and `onKeyDown()` and in them I call finish function but these events don't work.

Can any one help me why I finish this activity when back key is pressed???

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    super.onBackPressed();
    finish();
}
```

Comment: The code seems ok, did you test on device?

Comment: I don't have any devices .I tested it with sdk emultor and youwave.

Comment: My guess is that it's a youwave emulator issue than.

Comment: if I don't overwrite  onBackPress , does it close activity(even with web view in my layout)?

Comment: Theoretically, yes. If you are in the top activity in the navigation stack it will send it to the background. Calling finish() will make sure that you can't relaunch the activity. (I don't know if that is what you want to achieve.

Comment: you don't need to override the onBackPressed method. the default behavior is to finish the activity...